# Refering from image resources to images in the packages folder in VS 2015

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package-restore

For a certain project, I needed to create different NuGet packages which contained images. Then, I needed to install these packages in the project and put the images in forms. This all went smoothly.

My problem is, when I checkout to another branch in Git, and do a package restore, for some reason Visual Studio isn't able to find the images which were used in the forms. For it to work, I need to manually type in the following command on solution level:

```
Update-Package Reinstall
```

After I did this, everything was building again. The problem is, I don't want to do this every time I switch branches in Git. I already looked if Visual Studio had a solution to this problem, but all I could find was this: [Linked and Embedded Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht9h2dk8(v=vs.100).aspx).

I want that when I do a package restore, Visual Studio replaces the reference to the image, so it will always recognize the images after a package restore. My question: Is this even possible, and if it is, how?

I hope you have enough information to be able to answer this question. Thanks!

---

EDIT:
Okay, so let me rephrase the problem here. When I restore the packages, it only restores the file in the `\packages\` folder. That means, when I clone the repository locally, there isn't anything in the project resources folder, since I said in the .gitignore images should be ignored. So when I restore it doesn't update the `\packages\` folder. 
That's why I'd like there to be references to the `\packages\` folder, inside the resources folder.

For example:

There is an image in the package Package1.1.0.0. called Img1. When I install the package, it saves the image under the following path.

```
\packages\Package1.1.0.0.\Resources\Icons\Img1.png
```

\packages is the folder underneath the solution.

In the project in which I installed the package, there is also an Img1. That image is saved here:

```
\project\Resources\Icons\Img1.png
```

project is saved underneath the solution.

Now, I want the Img1.png doesn't contain the file itself, but rather a reference to the Img1.png in the packages folder. Also, when I update the package to version 1.0.1, I want Visual Studio to still have the reference to the Img1.png correctly.

---

EDIT:

Okay, so I did a bit of looking around, and I found out that my exact problem is an issue on the GitHub page of NuGet: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2895.

Comment: If your exact problem is the same as the issue on the GitHub, I suggest you can update your question or delete it, then add comment on the GitHub page, which is benefit to other communities Clear your question and easy to find the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correct, the images in the form should be referred using  the relative path of the corresponding package folder. e.g.

> /Packages/Package1/Images/Img1.png

In this way they should be able to get resolved even in the new branch once the package is restored and available in the packages folder.

Just to be sure check if the image path correctly set in the form.

Comment: I thought I wanted to reply, but then I thought of a possible solution, accidentally pressed enter, so yeah...

Comment: Ok. Then probably it would be helpful to someone if you could update your question or add an answer with your solution.

Comment: I edited the original post, hope this clarifies it a bit better.

Comment: Also, with your answer, I wouldn't be able to update the package to a newer version, since the folder would look like this: `/packages/package1.1.0.0/Images/Img1.png`. 1.0.0. is the version of the package. When I update my package, it makes a new folder: `/packages/package1.1.0.1/` and it deletes the old one, making the reference to the image unfindable.

Comment: This might help in your case. [Creating a Nuget package that will install files relative to the solution](http://www.vicesoftware.com/nuget/creating-a-nuget-package-that-will-install-files-relative-to-the-solution/)

Answer (score 0):

If you question is "*when I do a package restore, Visual Studio replaces the reference to the image, so it will always recognize the images after a package restore*".

Just as your comment, when you update the package from package 1.1.0.0 to package 1.1.0.1, the old package 1.1.0.0 will be deleted and the reference  also will be broken. So need to manually type following command on solution level:

```
Update-Package Reinstall
```

If you want update the package to version 1.0.1, and Visual Studio still have the reference to the Img1.png correctly, you could **pack this Img1.png into a package separately rather than included it in the package1.1.0.0**. In this case, when you update the package 1.1.0.0 to 1.1.0.1 will not break the reference of the package Img1.png